# Masking the original url

Tags: .htaccess, masking, url-masking, domain-masking

I want to mask a url name in addressbar. I don't know how to do it. I have two domains. `www.domainA.com` and `www.domainB.com`. When user goes to `www.domainB.com/subdirectory`, he should redirect to `www.domainA.com/subdirectory`, but in address bar it should be `www.domainB.com/subdirectory`.

Now i have redirected the url from `www.domainB.com/subdirectory` to `www.domainA.com/subdirectory`, but it shows `www.domainA.com/subdirectory`, instead of `www.domainB.com/subdirectory`

How to mask it, please suggest